# numpy.genfromtxt: delimiter=',' fails to split string

Tags: python, numpy, genfromtxt

I don't understand why `numpy.genfromtxt` doesn't split the following string correctly using `delimiter=","` while it works for most of the other strings in my chunk.

```
chunk[12968]
Out[143]: '2901869281,3279442095,2012-12-15T23:00:00.003Z,Sacramento,CA,R#3817874,United States,38.583,-121.498,11, 8, 6, 5, 1, 0, 2, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3, 2, 2, 6, 6, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,130\n'
```

I would expect an array of shape (110,) but get the following

```
genfromtxt([chunk[12968]],delimiter=",",dtype=np.int64)
Out[142]: 
array([2901869281, 3279442095,         -1,         -1,         -1,
               -1], dtype=int64)
```

Note that I am using `izip_longest` from `itertools` to read a large *csv by chunks this way:

```
with open('events.csv','r') as:
    for chunk in izip_longest(*[f] *50000):
          ...
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `comments` argument to [`genfromtxt()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) defaults to `'#'`, so everything past the `#` in your input is getting ignored:

```
2901869281,3279442095,2012-12-15T23:00:00.003Z,Sacramento,CA,R#3817874,United States,...
                                                              ^ start of comment
```